# ActiveRecord UknownAttributeError in my unit tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, activerecord, rspec-rails

Hi I have the following model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    acts_as_messageable

    before_save { email.downcase! }
    before_create :create_remember_token
    has_many :items , dependent: :destroy
    has_many :routes , dependent: :destroy
    has_many :bids, dependent: :destroy
    ....
 end

class Bid < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_one :package
    ....
end

class Package < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :bids, dependent: :destroy
   ....
end
```

when I run my unit tests I get the following error

> Failure/Error: @bid = user.bids.build(amount: 34.00)
>        ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError:
>          unknown attribute: user_id

My unit tests start as bellow

```
describe Bid do

let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

  before { 
    @package = user.packages.build(destination: "Dublin", origin: "Naas", length: 4.9, width: 5.0, height: 9, weight:32, delivery_date: Time.now)
    @bid = user.bids.build(amount: 34.00) 
  }
  ....
end
```

I'm not sure what is causing this error, I have a feeling it is something small because I can create a bid in the rails console with

```
u = User.new
bid = u.bids.build(amount: 33)
bid.save
```

The Bids table in my database has the column user_id so I don't know what it's complaining about? When I get this error fixed I'm slightly concerned that this might be circular dependency, it's just a feeling if anyone can confirm this or not that would also be great.

I would like to solve this before I write the code for the view and controller, because I'm trying to discipline myself to TDD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you forgot to migrate your test database? So the code is running fine in development but not on test?

run
`$ rake db:test:clone_structure`

FactoryGirl does also have a [better way](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#associations) handling associations

Comment: I'm going to go hit my head off a wall, this is my second night trying to fix that. Thanks for your help and the link to FactoryGirl, i've been meaning to learn more about it. I'll get used to rails yet, I'm too used to .net and Visual Studio.

Comment: U can also place the following line into your test_helper/spec_helper
`ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!` 
It will throw an exception if you've forgot to migrate the test db